# CakePHP - how could I bind comment form with current post?

Tags: cakephp

I have site with single `Post` which has comment form. How could I receive `id` of post in my `add()` method of Comment controller?
Thx!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the models are binded correctly (Post hasMany Comment, Comment belongsTo Post) you can do it like that:

/views/comments/add.ctp or /views/posts/view.php:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('post_id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, one more question, should I bind models in 2 ways? (just like you wrote: Post hasMany Comment, Comment belongsTo Post)?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your question. You should bind model according to their real-life relationship. Here, if You were to have only the Comment belongsTo Post relationship it would be enough.